# Sampling from user provided target densities in PyMC3

Tags: pymc, pymc3

Is it possible to sample from a user provided target measure in PyMC3 in an easy way? I.e. I want to be able to provide black box functions `logposterior(theta)` and `grad_logposterior(theta)` that and sample from those instead of specifying a model in PyMC3s modeling language.

Comment: Does this example meet your needs? https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/arbitrary_stochastic.py  If not, please expand your question to show what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: The problem with this example is that `logp` is still an expression (which PyMC3 can use to compute the symbolic gradient and hessian), while I am talking about _black box functions_ that can only be evaluated. Edited the question to be more clear here.
The reasoning for this is that I already have a collection of target densities with accompanying gradient functions and would like to not have to transform them all into PyMC3/Theano expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit clunky. You'd need to create a new Theano `Op`. Here are a few examples: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/slinalg.py#L32

You then need to create a distribution class that evaluates the logp via your new `Op`, for example: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/distributions/continuous.py#L70

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the best way. Thanks a lot! But you're right its clunky, and easier to rewrite as Theono expressions after all.

Comment: If you have an example, please consider doing a PR as I'm sure it's not an overly uncommon use-case.